# SCons look for files in multiple directories

Tags: scons

So I'm new to scons and I'm having some trouble with figuring out how I can look in multiple directories?

This is my current approach which works fine for a single folder:

```
files = File([
    'testfile.c',
    'testfile_const.c',
    'folder/testfile2.c',
    'folder/testfile2_const.c'

])


dir = Dir('.')
env.Append(CPPPATH = dir)
env.Prepend(CPPPATH = dir.srcnode())
Return('files')
```

The thing is, now that i've put `testfile2` in its own folder, my scons script complains. How can I look for files in another directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all the directories to be part of the CPPPATH, you will need to add them explicitly. This could be done pretty simply with your current approach by using a for loop:

```py
import os

# Use all C/C++ files in this folder
files = File([
    'testfile.c',
    'testfile_const.c',
    'folder/testfile2.c',
    'folder/testfile2_const.c'

])

# Add folder to search path
for file in files:
    dirpath = os.path.dirname(file.path)
    if not dirpath in env['CPPPATH']:
        env.Append(CPPPATH = [dirpath])

Return('files')
```

Comment: I'd add there's no reason to create File objects for these. You can just handle them as strings if you want and use os.dirname().